# Perishable Documents?

Tags: mongodb

Is there any way that MongoDB handles the deletion of documents automaticaly based on time?

I use Tornado (Python) and the `IOLoop` can do it, but it checks always for time, and the life of those documents is high (6 mounth),

So can Mongodb do it without making a clickable script or using the IOLoop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a feature (new in 2.1) called TTL (time-to-live) indexes.

You can read all about them including examples here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/

Comment: ah, that's what i need, so i just create a special index for the field that i want to make it  perishable! thank you :)